# why splash screen not showing in react native?

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

i am trying to make a splash screen but it doesn't show any way

```
App:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image,Button,backgroundImage, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import Box from './src/box';
import splash from './src/splash'
//import ImagesExample from './ImagesExample.js'

export default class App extends React.Component {

componentWillMount() {
        setState = {
            View : <splash />
        };


        setTimeout(() => {
            //IF FALSE NAVIGATE TO ERROR
            if(true) {
                this.setState({
                    View : <splash/>
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    View : <splash/>
                })
            }
        }, 2000) //TIME OF WAITING


    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1,justifyContent: 'center',}}>

       <Image
                  source={require('./assets/hamburger.png')}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  style={styles.background}
                >
                </Image>

      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center',flex:5}}>

splash:

import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar , View , Text , ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class splash extends React.Component {

   render() {
       return (


<View style={{ flex: 1 , justifyContent: 'center' , alignItems: 'center' , backgroundColor : '#34495e'}}>

                <Text style={{ color : 'white',fontSize : 18 }}>Hello Splash</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator color={'white'}/> //YOUR SPINNER WAITING
            </View>


       );
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question and remove the duplicated sentences? What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: nothing happened, it just run the app from app.js, it skipped the splash screen, did I forgot something?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an Splash like this:

```
export default class SplashScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    handleSplash = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            //navigate to Home page
        }, 2500)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleSplash()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <Text>Splash</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: should I announce it on app.json?

Comment: you don't need to edit app.json. you can use app.js (index.js) as splash or make a new file and call it from app.js (index.js). when this page starts, it will navigate to Home screen after 2.5 seconds. if you need more information, let me know :)

Comment: and how do I call it(the splash screen)  from app/index and back after 2.5 seconds to app/index? what do I need to write there?

Comment: there is some packages that controls your apps navigations. by using this packages you can lunch a new screen or make tab bar or drawer navigation. one of them is https://reactnavigation.org that i'm use..